# There's something wrong with the day and night mode switch in my android code

Tags: android, material-components-android

I set my day and night mode just like the way given in demo`https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/tree/master/catalog/java/io/material/catalog/themeswitcher`, but there are some problems.

Here is the relevant code about my question(but there's too much code, So I can't guarantee that the relevant code I understand is correct）

```
MaterialButtonToggleGroup themeToggleGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.theme_toggle_group);
    themeToggleGroup.check(themePreferencesManager.getCurrentThemeId());

    themeToggleGroup.addOnButtonCheckedListener((group, checkedId, isChecked) -> {
      if (isChecked) {
        themePreferencesManager.saveAndApplyTheme(checkedId);
      }
    });
```

```
public void saveAndApplyTheme(@IdRes int id) {
    int nightMode = convertToNightMode(id);
    saveNightMode(nightMode);
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(nightMode);
  }
```

```
private void saveNightMode(int nightMode) {
    getSharedPreferences().edit().putInt(KEY_NIGHT_MODE, nightMode).commit();
  }
```

**KEY_NIGHT_MODE**   is just a key,it can be ignored.

As shown in the example, as long as you press the button, you will switch between day and night, but mine doesn't seem to work, only when you manually recreate activity.

The other config is also the same to the demo,so  I want to ask why this phenomenon will happen?**I guess itmay be an empirical question**

In the demo, the day and night mode will switch quickly after clicking the button, but mine is not. I want to know who has experience in this kind of problem, thank you!

Comment: `just like the way given in demo` that demo link can be changed, removed, outdated... anything, and people here don't feel like clicking on another link just to see what you're doing, so don't `i'm doing it like this off-site resource here` but instead include enough information in your post _here_ for others to help

Comment: thanks,I’ll change it immediately

Comment: no problem, it's just really important to include all information here, otherwise people in future might want to click on that link you've provided and it'll be gone, then it isn't useful to others :)

Comment: Thank you very much. Stackoverflow is a website that can move me, because I can feel valued! And there are users who can give me suggestions to modify or help me edit problems without asking for return! Because these things are almost impossible in China! I am very moved!